# Vue router is not working. The page is not found when I search for the path

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using laravel 10 and vue 3. My routes not working . I don't know where is the problem. Here is the code.

**welcome.blade.php**

```
 <div id="app">    
        @vite('resources/js/app.js')
        </div>
```

**app.vue**

```
<template>
    <div >
        <h2>Laravel 10</h2>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```
import './bootstrap';
import {createApp} from 'vue';
import app from './layouts/app.vue';
import router from './routes.js';
createApp(app).use(router).mount('#app');
```

**routes.js**

```
import { createWebHistory,createRouter} from "vue-router";   
import Home from './pages/Home.vue';
import register from './pages/auth/admin/register.vue';
import login from './pages/auth/admin/login.vue';

 const routes = [
    {
        path:'/home',
        name:'Home',
        component:Home,
    },
    {
        path:'/register',
        name: 'register',
        component:register,
    },
    {
        path:'/login',
        name:'Login',
        component:login,
    }
];

const router =  createRouter({
    //  mode:'history',
    history:createWebHistory(),
    routes,
});
export default router;
```

It works fine when I have defined createApp(app).mount('#app'); but it's not working when I defined createApp.use(router).mount('#app');
This error occurs  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: What is the URL of the resource you get a 404 for? Check in your browser's developer console, in the network tab. You *probably* need a catch-all route in your Laravel routes file, to direct all unknown URLs to Vue; something like `Route::get('/{any?}', 'AppController@view');`

Comment: these are my url http://127.0.0.1:8000/home, http://127.0.0.1:8000/register, http://127.0.0.1:8000/login, and these are in web.php Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Comment: But this works Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
,Can you please explain whats the difference and why does it work?

Comment: Laravel doesn't know about Vue's routes, so if you visit `/register` it doesn't know anything about it. The `/{any?}` approach tells Laravel to just serve your SPA for any route, and lets Vue handle the rest from there.

Comment: but any code of in welcome.blade.php is not working. can you help me on this issue?

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: <div id="app">
            <h4>Hello</h4>
        </div> in here hello or any tag not showing ,it;s only showing from app.vue